# fastest backup for large files

Tags: backup, rsync, tar, mirror

what is the fastest way to duplicate a folder contain few files with few hundred megs size and other few megs small files? (say, /var/lib/mysql)
cp or tar or rsync or...??

Comment: When you say duplicate, do are you trying to just copy the data to another directory, partition , disk or across a network ?

Comment: the fastest one first (perhaps another directory/partition/disk). then the result will be backup again using other better method accross network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rsync in general will be faster than cp or tar, because rsync only transfers those files which have changed, and with --partial it will only transfer the parts of a file that changed.

Having said that, rsync works much better if you know what you're backupping and can arrange things so that rsync doesn't have to do as much work.  For example, rotated log files in /var/log work much better if you rotate them to a filename with a date in it, instead of .0, .1, .2, etc..

One more note:  In your question you mention /var/lib/mysql.  Using rsync to backup that is a pretty bad idea, use mysqldump to get a reliable backup.  If that backup is too large to transfer frequently, use mysql replication and backup from a slave.  (You still should do a full backup on the master periodically though, replication can fail too).

Comment: rom man rsync: "--partial   keep partially transferred files".  It does not transfer only what changed in a file. If a file changed, the entire file gets transfered.

Comment: Yes, this is slightly inaccurate. --partial keeps partially copied files on the sender if the transfer is aborted. It has nothing to do with the rsync algorithm that transfers only parts of partially changed files, which is on by default (although can be turned off with --whole-file).

Answer (score 1):

Depends on a few factors.  For a large number of small files it is generally better to do tar.  If it is a small number of large files, cp is ok in most instances.

If you have a list of files but only a small portion of them change, rsync is more efficient.

Comment: example is /var/lib/mysql which contain not much files and most of them relative big

Comment: If you're planning on backup up mysql files, be sure to have a look at the mysql docs.  There are a few traps to watch out for http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/backup-strategy-summary.html

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are backing up. You can't just backup live database with rsync, you'll end you with a corrupted file. For databases, like mysql, you need to set cron, for example, to run 'mysqldump' and then rsync that file. Also, make sure you append 'date' with the file name so, you know when this file was backed up and have several backup copies just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the magic word `backup`

I can't say much about relative speeds of the methods you mention, but I think `rsync`'s ability to backup only files which have changed, makes it the best method.

Especially if most of the files don't need to be copied.

Answer (score 0):

If you have quite a few small files, running a `tar` over them will increase the transfer speed considerably.

If the files are mostly text (which isn't the case of mysql binaries or databases), consider zipping the tar (`bzip2` and the like). Otherwise you won't get anything from the compression so just leave the tar alone.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already have an older copy of the files and you only need to refresh the copy, then rsync is much faster than cp or tar because it only transfers the bytes that have changed. A 100MB file with a few changed records will update in a few seconds. I have found it to be perfect for database files but I have had less success with binary files.

But if the purpose of the copy is for off-site backup, nothing comes near to rdiff-backup. rdiff-backup, like rsync, only transfers changes within files, but it also maintains the incremental changes so that you can restore any file from any earlier backup date.

And, as for the SQL databases, rdiff-backup checks for changes made during the backup and fixes them automatically, so IMHO it should be safe. Unless, of course the SQL server holds data in memory without writing it to disk - then it will not be safe.

Answer (score 0):

SAN Snapshot is *the* fastest way, but probably not the answer you were looking for.